# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Role_Registry_Exception' with message 'Role 'admin' not found

Tags: zend-framework

ZEND FRAMEWORL: I have this error when coding my ACL. how can I solve this? I already have a database with a data field role. I don't know the problem

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Role_Registry_Exception' with message 'Role 'admin' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend3\zend3\library\Zend\Acl\Role\Registry.php:132 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend3\zend3\library\Zend\Acl.php(837): Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->get('admin') #1 
>   this is my bootstrap.php

Comment: Could you add the minimum amount of code required to duplicate this issue?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some sample code, it appears as though you are attempting to assign a 'role' to a 'resource' without having defined the 'role'.

Here is a **basic** example of setting up ACL.

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('someResource'));
$acl->allow('admin', 'someResource');
```

Your error message is saying you have missed the second line of code (`$acl->addRole(...);`)

[Zend ACL Introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.introduction.html)